# Subwoofer not working in HP Pavilion m6-1002tx

Tags: sound, hp

I have HP pavilion m6-1002tx dual boot (Windows 7 Home Premium & Ubuntu 13.04),64-bit. I find no sign of a working subwoofer, at back side of my laptop. Also in `all setting->sounds`, the option of woofer is inactive. As I'm new to ubuntu, I expect something to set it working, with help of extra sound drivers to be installed, if needed so!

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Check alsamixer (`alsamixer` in terminal), to see that the subwoofer is not muted which sometimes may be happen.

Otherwise editing `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` usually works

In terminal run `gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

Add the following at the end then save:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

or

```
options snd-hda-intel model=ref
```

Then reboot.
Check alsamixer and sound settings again after each attempt.

`/usr/share/doc/alsa-base/driver/HD-Audio-Models.txt.gz` has a list of models to put instead of `auto/ref`, I don't see your model in there, but maybe one of the others using the same codec will work.

Run `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec` to discover your codec (mine is `92hd91`), so not supported there either, but sometimes one of the others does the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-ppa-repository ppa:diwic/hda
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hda-jack-retask
hda-jack-retask
```

1. Chose your sound card
2. Check "Show unconnected pins"
3. Try to override pins one by one switching to "Internal
   speaker(LFE)". It was id:0x10 in my case.

Don't forget aplly after every change and check result. After you found the right pin press "Install boot ovverride"